# Problems running the installer for Parrot OS on VM Ware

Tags: vmware-fusion, parrot-os

I tried downloading and installing Parrot OS on VM Ware.

In the options menu on boot, I selected Install.

Clicking next through each option, the install media is not recognized when you get to the screen past the keyboard select screen. I tried Alt + F2 and dropped into a console to look for the mounted virtual cdrom media but could find none.

I am stuck at this point in the process as nothing will install.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by selecting the Live boot option instead of install. Then I ran the installer from the live desktop and everything worked fine.